# Compare two tables and show data with missing value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Master` and `Log` as shown below. And require an output along with the a new entry of emp who is missing from log table for particular workweek and year when compared with master. I tried with multiple join, left, left outer, but not able to figure out to match and get workweek for emp missing data from log table. Any help or example will be helpful

```
Master table              Log table

empid|Name                empid|name|workweek|year|attendance
-----+-----               -----+----+--------+----+-----------
 1   | XYZ                   1 | XYZ|  1     |2023|Present
 2   | abz                   2 | abz|  1     |2023|Present
 3   | yzz                   2 | abz|  2     |2023|Present
                             3 | yzz|  2     |2023|Present
```

Desired output:

```
 empid|name|workweek|year|attendance
 -----+----+--------+----+-------------
   1  | XYZ|  1     |2023|Present
   2  | abz|  1     |2023|Present
   3  | yzz|  1     |2023|Absent
   2  | abz|  2     |2023|Present
   3  | yzz|  2     |2023|Present
   1  | XYZ|  2     |2023|Absent
```

This is my query:

```
select *
from log l
left join Master M on l.empid = m.empid
```

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

based on the expected output, you are looking to see all entries in master table by each workweek in 2023 to be in the final output, indicating if the employee was present or absent.

Here is a way to do this

```
with master_data
  as (select empid,name,workweek,year
        from (select distinct workweek,year from log) a
        join master b
          on 1=1 --This does a cartersian join
      )
  select md.empid,md.name,md.workweek,md.year
         ,case when l.attendence is null then
                   'Absent'
           else 'Present'
          end as Attendence
    from master_data md
left join log l
       on md.empid=l.empid
      and md.workweek=l.workweek
      and md.year=l.year
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives invalid column name for workweek and year at the second line of the query

Comment: Just put a single quote after 'Present and the query should then execute OK

Comment: Thanks craig, that change was done. issue is at this second line a (select empid,name,workweek,year here it says workweek and year are invalid columns seems like (select distinct workweek,year from log) this is not able to create column into master_data

Comment: Kindly let me know if anything wrong approach i am trying

Comment: could you check if putting the alias on the select query fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Prepare scene

Master

```
declare @Master table (empid int not null primary key , Name nvarchar(20))
insert @Master 
values 
( 1 ,'XYZ'),
( 2 ,'abz'),
( 3 ,'yzz')
```

Log

```
declare @Log table (empid int , Name nvarchar(20),workweek int,year int, attendance nvarchar(20))

insert @Log 
values
( 1, 'XYZ', 1,2023,'Present'),
( 2, 'abz', 1,2023,'Present'),
( 2, 'abz', 2,2023,'Present'),
( 3, 'yzz', 2,2023,'Present')
```

Solution :

some variables You need

```
declare @Year int = 2023

declare @Date datetime = '1.1.'+convert(nvarchar(4),@Year)
declare @MaxDate datetime = dateadd(week,-1,dateAdd(year,1,@Date))
```

Request itself

```
;with cte as (
    
    select Workweek = datepart(Week,@Date)
            , D = @Date
            , Year = @Year
    
    union all
    
    select Workweek = datepart(Week,DATEADD(week,1,D))
    , D = DATEADD(week,1,D)
    , Year = @Year 
    from Cte where D < @MaxDate
)

select 
      M.empid
    , M.Name
    , C.Workweek
    , C.Year
    , attendance = isnull(L.attendance,'Absent')
from cte C
join @Master M on 1=1
left join @Log L on L.empid = M.empid and L.workweek = C.WNum

where C.Workweek <= ( select max(workweek) from @Log where year = @Year)
and C.year = @Year
```

Result

```
empid       Name                 Workweek    Year        attendance
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
1           XYZ                  1           2023        Present
2           abz                  1           2023        Present
3           yzz                  1           2023        Absent
1           XYZ                  2           2023        Absent
2           abz                  2           2023        Present
3           yzz                  2           2023        Present
```